# Use "execdll.exe" to invoke a method in a C# DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Please I need to know if it is possible to execute a method with a c#.net dll using **execdll.exe**.

I'm try to execute a simple method Hello World but I get the error "Unable to browse functions of this file". I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean rundll32.exe or at least execdll.exe is something similar.

.NET classes can't be exposed as plain DLLs. They can be exposed as COM DLLs though. So the only way to make what you want is to expose .NET class as COM and then write a regular DLL (in C++, Delphi or so) that would instantiate your COM object and call it. You can then call your DLL from rundll32.exe or whatever tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Assemblies for that

```
Assembly.Load(byteArrayOfDll).EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: Please how can I achieve that. This is my dll below


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    namespace MainLibrary
    {
    public class Class1
    {      
        public static String HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Good to go";
        }
    }
    }

Comment: Compile the Executable and add it as a file to the resources of your main file. Then use the line above `(byteArrayOfDll is Resources.testexe)` and then the executable will launch.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the method is Public,

.

**Another thing**: Only Static Methods make sense in your context

I am in favour of @Devils Child approach:

run the DLL from your process...

if you can, reference it at design-time...

or use Reflection at run-time...

and if it is not a static method, use Activator (as needed)

Best regards.

Comment: But I need to call the function through the program *execdll.exe*. My functions seems to be public but I still get the same error

Comment: @Jay Why do you need to call execdll.exe ???

is your method private or Public ?
can you post your DLL?

Comment: I was given the application in order to test the dll. This is my dll Sir: 
**using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; namespace MainLibrary { public class Class1 { public static String HelloWorld() { return "Good to go"; } } }**